# Retrieve array buffer and an error from rest api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a method that calls RESTful service and retrieves a file:

```
this.generateReport = function (...) {
    return $http(
    {
        url: "...",
        method: "POST",
        responseType: "arraybuffer",
        data: ...
    });
};
```

I am calling this method from the controller:

```
reportService.generateReport(...).
    then(function (response) {
        ...
    }, function (reason) {
        ...
    });
```

This piece of code works and I can retrieve files. The question is how to handle an error response from web api?

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("...")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetFile(...)
{
    ...
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Some error");
}
```

When returning the error I am getting it as a byte array. Do I need to convert it to string or there are some better ways to do this in `AngularJS v1.5.7`?

[image]

Comment: what does your return $http does? where are you returning it?

Comment: It returns a promise and I am calling that function from a service. let me edit the question.

Comment: you need to defer the service

Comment: If you're getting a byte array it did not return the internal server error response. If the API returns an error, angular goes into the second callback of the `.then` function

Comment: I know it goes to second part, but it has an array of bytes there, I think because it expects `responseType: "arraybuffer"`